# How can I put a button at the top of a select2?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I use Bootstrap 4.6 and select2 v4.0.13 with bootstrap4 theme. I can't find an elegant way to put a button at the top right of a select2 like that : [image here : select2 with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMghC.jpg).

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance !

T.

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: You will need to add your code. what have you try?